# Using javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam for passing JSON parameter

Tags: java, json, web-services, get, jax-rs

I'm developing a rest web service using jax rs. In the current method i want to hava a @GET request where the user is passing a json parameter named "request" using the header of the http request.

Code:

```
    @GET
    @Path("load")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public LoadUserResponse load(@HeaderParam("request") LoadUserRequest sRequest) throws Exception{


        User user= userBean.load(sRequest.getId());

        LoadUserResponse response = new LoadUserResponse();
        response.Transform(user);

        return response;
    }
```

this code gives me the exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a constructor that takes a String param or a valueOf() or fromString() method for javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam(\"request\") on public com.totempool.rest.responses.LoadUserResponse com.totempool.rest.services.UserService.load(com.totempool.rest.requests.LoadUserRequest) throws java.lang.Exception for basetype: com.totempool.rest.requests.LoadUserRequest"}}
```

POJO class:

```
package com.totempool.rest.requests;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement
public class LoadUserRequest {

    @XmlElement(name="id")
    private long id;

    public LoadUserRequest(){

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public LoadUserRequest fromString(String param){
        return null;

    }

}
```

My question is , is there a way to pass a @HeaderParam and autoparse it to the object?

By autoparse i mean something like this:

```
    @POST
    @Path("list")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ListUserResponse list(ListUserRequest request) throws Exception{

        List<User> users= userBean.list();
        ListUserResponse response = new ListUserResponse();
        response.Transform(users);

        return response;

    }
```

with this code the app will recognize the json send and parse it into an object.

A POSSIBLE OPTION BUT NOT SUITABLE FOR WHAT I NEED:

```
    @GET
    @Path("load")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public LoadUserResponse load(@HeaderParam("request") String sRequest) throws Exception{

        ObjectMapper map= new ObjectMapper();
        LoadUserRequest request=map.readValue(sRequest, LoadUserRequest.class);
        User user= userBean.load(request.getId());

        LoadUserResponse response = new LoadUserResponse();
        response.Transform(user);

        return response;
    }
```

here i'm getting the string send and then parsing it manually, the problem is that the web service may have several similar methods and i don't want to do this manually in every one of them.

Comment: The exception explains exactly what is required. `LoaderUserRequest` should have a  constructor with a String arg, or a static `valueOf(String)`, or a static `fromString(String)`, that latter two returning an instance of `LoaderUserRequest`. Either way, you will still need to use the object mapper to actually create the object wit the passed in string. This is just how `@HeaderParam` works, as well as other `@XxxParam` annotations. The value type available is String, so you need to do something with it

Comment: As an aside, why are we using JSON in a header anyway. Seems like something that could be past as a query param (you're only using the id anyway). Or maybe even a path param.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it works with the following solution (GSON from Google). I don't know if this is the best one, but it works :-) I put this code in every REST-Transfer-Class.

```
/**
 * Parse JSON to Object.
 * 
 * @param p_json JSON String
 * @return Object
 */
public static POJO_XY valueOf(String p_json) {
    return gson.fromJson(p_json, POJO_XY.class);
}
```